# php get variables aren't in the link

Tags: php, html, get

Here is what Opera Dragonfly shows me:

```
<form action="rejectQuestion.php?q_id=24" id="reject_question" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Reject" id="form_button"/>
</form>
```

but after clicking submit button here is what I get:

`http://project/rejectQuestion.php?` , so no arguments are there. Same thing is on another form. Is it server problems or I am so wicked sick that I can't see code problem?

Comment: Give your button a `name`.

Comment: Is that really required? hmmmm...

Comment: that won't have any affect

Comment: @PeeHaa this is actually what I think about. I used some time ago the way I posted here, but then I used my friends `.htaccess` file and may be it is because of that...

Comment: It doesn't work or just you don't see query string in browser url field? recent versions of internet browsers hides params in query string, you have to focus on url bar to see it.

Comment: No, I watch parameters, and by assigning name to the button I can see parameter called reject

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a form has `method="get"`, it overwrites any query string in the `action` with the form data to send. Therefore if you want any "fixed" values, you have to add them as hidden inputs:

```
<form action="rejectQuestion.php" id="reject_question" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="24" />
  <input type="submit" value="Reject" id="form_button" />
</form>
```

***HOWEVER***... The HTTP specification explicitly states that GET requests must NOT be used for anything transformative, such as what you seem to be doing judging by the name "reject question". You SHOULD use a `POST` request for this.

One reason why this should be done is to prevent fraudulent requests. A malicious user could easily send the "delete" link to an unsuspecting user and the victim could find their stuff gone. It doesn't even have to be a link that is clicked on, a malicious user could simply post what looks like a broken image on a public forum, but it actually made the request to the server and modified or deleted stuff.

ALL transformative requests should be `POST`, never `GET`. `GET` should be used for *getting* stuff only.

Comment: That is very informative, thanks. I was going to check user cookie with the id sent, but now I guess I will change my decision.

Answer (score 3):

Add hidden input to your form

```
<form action="rejectQuestion.php" id="reject_question" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="24">
<input type="submit" value="Reject" id="form_button">
</form>
```

You have to do it this way, because when using the `GET` method in your form it overrides the querystring used in the `action` of the form.

Another way would be to let the form use the `POST` method and in that case the querystring will be left alone. Although this may get confusing on the backend because there would both be values in the `GET` and the `POST` superglobals.

Comment: @RyanNaddy This is an Q&A site. If this doesn't answer the question it is not really a good fit imho.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it isn't the best way, and I like my code as good as I can. Thanks though

Comment: @PeeHaa yeah I understand. I'm new here and trying to learn these 'rules' :)

Comment: @ECode It's ok. I hope you don't mind that I have edited in the "missing" information :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you use GET parameters in the `action` URL and have `method="get"`.

This causes the browser to throw away the query string from the `action` and only use the (in your case empty) one based on the form fields. For this reason you either need to use `method="POST"` (which is a good idea anyway since you are going to modify data with the request) or move the `q_id` into a hidden form field. Actually you should do that even when using POST. No need to pass the ID via GET.

```
<form action="rejectQuestion.php?q_id=24" id="reject_question" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="24" />
  <input type="submit" value="Reject" id="form_button" />
</form>
```